# Are there any ways that can check whether the data I am trying to store is already existed in the blockchain or not?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm trying to store user data ( name, national identity number, birthday,etc.) **by converting all data into hash and store it in the input field of block in the Blockchain**. **But , the problem is that how can I know  data I am trying to store is already existed in the blockchain cause I want to prevent data duplicate** . I am running my blockchain on local private network using geth. By the way, is my data storing method okay or should I change to use smart contract for storing data.

Answer (score 0):

It should be OK to use a transaction's input field to store data, but you will have some limitations:

- It is not indexed so data there cannot be easily queried. You can create and maintain an external index though.
- It is unmodifiable. Once a transaction is mined it cannot be modified.

---

One possible solution in Ethereum is to use a smart contract to store and query data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you answer me one more question please?   As I mentioned in this post, when user try to store data into blockchain, how can I notify and reject to store his data in blockchain if  that data already exists  in blockchain ? Is it possible?

Comment: @MayThanzin It depends on the storage solution you choose. It is easy if you use a smart contract, you can use a mapping to index stored your data, if it already exists you can reject any change, or require some permissions in order to modify it.